# override shiro unauthorized page

Tags: security, shiro

I need to know how to override shiro unauthorized page. i.e. when a user does not have some permission for a protected url, shiro return page 401. how we can make it forward user to a pre-defined unauthorized  page?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

I found only one way, how to change redirection to login.jsp to response with 401.

You should create your own Filter, which will extend org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter, and override saveRequestAndRedirectToLogin() method.

```
public class SecurityAuthenticationFilter extends FormAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    protected void saveRequestAndRedirectToLogin(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        saveRequest(request);
        sendChallenge(response);
    }

    protected void sendChallenge(ServletResponse response) {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = WebUtils.toHttp(response);
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

}
```

I use Guice + Shiro integration. So, this filter is added same way as in the org.apache.shiro.guice.web.ShiroWebModule.

```
public class SecurityModule extends ShiroWebModule {

    public static final Key<SecurityAuthenticationFilter> AUTHC_REST = Key.get(SecurityAuthenticationFilter.class);

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configureShiroWeb() {
        ...

        // Add as filter
        addFilterChain("/rest/login", ANON);
        addFilterChain("/rest/**", AUTHC_REST);

        ...
    }
}
```

For shiro.ini file it should be added in following way:

```
[main]
authc = package.path.to.SecurityAuthenticationFilter

[urls]
/rest/login = anon
/rest/** = authc
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 0):

:) I need the other way around, I'd like to get a `401` instead of a redirect (`302`). What is your current setup? Can you configure this from `shiro.ini` file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which technology stack you're using, but in a Java webapp you can configure this in the web.xml within the  tag.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>401</error-code>
  <location>{path to custom page}</location>
</error-page>
```